# azure continuous deployment fails with nuget client version error on deployment command

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, nuget, continuous-deployment, kudu

[image: Screeshot from activity logs]

**Activity Logs**

> Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
>   Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
>   D:\home\site\repository.nuget\NuGet.targets(89,9): error : The 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' package requires NuGet client version '2.8.1' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40619.9041'. [D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\Plantao.Web.csproj]
>   D:\home\site\repository.nuget\NuGet.targets(89,9): error : The 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async 1.0.168' package requires NuGet client version '2.8.1' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40619.9041'. [D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\Plantao.Web.csproj]
>   D:\home\site\repository.nuget\NuGet.targets(89,9): error : The 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21' package requires NuGet client version '2.8.1' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40619.9041'. [D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\Plantao.Web.csproj]
>   D:\home\site\repository.nuget\NuGet.targets(89,9): error : The 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' package requires NuGet client version '2.8.1' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40619.9041'. [D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\Plantao.Web.csproj]
>   D:\home\site\repository.nuget\NuGet.targets(89,9): error : The 'Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40619.9041'. [D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\Plantao.Web.csproj]
>   D:\home\site\repository.nuget\NuGet.targets(89,9): error : The 'System.Net.Http 4.3.3' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40619.9041'. [D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\Plantao.Web.csproj]
>   D:\home\site\repository.nuget\NuGet.targets(89,9): error : The 'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms 4.3.1' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40619.9041'. [D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\Plantao.Web.csproj]
>   D:\home\site\repository.nuget\NuGet.targets(89,9): error : The 'System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding 4.3.0' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40619.9041'. [D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\Plantao.Web.csproj]
>   D:\home\site\repository.nuget\NuGet.targets(89,9): error : The 'System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives 4.3.0' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40619.9041'. [D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\Plantao.Web.csproj]
>   D:\home\site\repository.nuget\NuGet.targets(89,9): error : The 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates 4.3.2' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40619.9041'. [D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\Plantao.Web.csproj]
>   D:\home\site\repository.nuget\NuGet.targets(89,9): error : The 'System.ValueTuple 4.4.0' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40619.9041'. [D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\Plantao.Web.csproj]
>   D:\home\site\repository.nuget\NuGet.targets(89,9): error MSB3073: The command ""...nuget\NuGet.exe" install "D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "..\ " " exited with code 1. [D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\Plantao.Web.csproj]
>   Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\Plantao.Web\Plantao.Web.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\8d578a48eacd291";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false
>   An error has occurred during web site deployment.
>   \r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\71.10217.3259\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"

From what I was able to understand we need to update the kudu NuGet client, but I couldn't anything about it on the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure has `nuget 4.3.0.4406` installed, and by default, this is the one used to restore packages when building your project

I took a quick look at your kudu site:
[image]

You checked in your own version of nuget under `.nuget/` folder, was that on purpose?

Comment: not it was not, I try to delete it and see what happens

Comment: Remove the folder worked for the error, so I'm accepting the answer, but now I'm facing a new issue :'( thank you anyway